# Intersection of surface with parallel planes

Tags: plotting, geometry

Consider the code (adapted from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/HighlightTheIntersectionOfTwoSurfaces.html))

```
h = x^2 + y^2/9 + z^2/4 - 1;
g = z;
ContourPlot3D[
   {h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]}, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

Now I have few ideas on the effect of `MeshFunctions`. Anyway, the result is very nice for me.

[image]

I'd like to do the same but with a parallel plane with $z=k$ for other values of $k$ (for example, $k=1$).

So I tried the code

```
h = x^2 + y^2/9 + z^2/4 - 1;
g = z;
k := 1;
ContourPlot3D[
   {h == 0, g == k}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]}, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

and the result was

[image]

and (after reading some comments) I discovered that I can plot those two planes together simply using `{h == 0, g == k, g == 0}` obtaining

[image]

**Question:** How to get the sphere (to be true, an ellipsoid) together with two or three planes corresponding to different values of $k$ and their intersection (the blue curves) all on the same figure?

---

**ps:** I edited the post to help future readings and to follow the rich comments.

Comment: "I don't know the effect of MeshFunctions."  Have you looked it up in the documentation to try to understand what it does?

Comment: @Szabolcs, not yet. I was supposing that code was not relevant for the intersection. But based on your question I guess that I was wrong. I'll read it.

Comment: There's an example which probably gives what you want in the documentation of ContourPlot3D under MeshFunctions.  Although you did not actually say what you wanted to do (it is not obvious to me, I'm just guessing).

Comment: I'm trying to show hoe to obtains the surfaces (spheres, paraboloid, cones and so on) starting with their intersections with coordinate planes.

Comment: You may want to play around with `BoxRatios` to make it actually look like an ellipsoid.

Comment: Wow, in fact writing `Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]` here is incorrect and the fact that it works at all is an accident IMO.  It is interesting to see that this came from the documentation.  I'll write an answer later today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that you are interested in showing only the intersections for an arbitrary set of cutting planes parallel to the xy-plane. That can be achieved by making some small modifications to PatoCriollo's answer. Like so:

```
h = x^2 + y^2/9 + z^2/4 - 1;
With[{cuts = Range[-5/2, 5/2, 1/2]}, 
  ContourPlot3D[h == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 2}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, z]}, 
    MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {cuts}, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]]]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Edit

On second thought, there is no need for `g` at all. The code above has been edited to eliminate `g`. This is much faster.

Comment: lol perfect! Now I can teach my students about quadratic surfaces. Thanks so much. I'll try to adapt it to show other circles for other planes ($x$ or $y$ constants).

Answer (score 9):

```
 h = x^2 + y^2/9 + z^2/4 - 1;
g = z;
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0, g == k}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -3, 
  3}, {z, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, z]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0, k }}, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is it possible to show/hide the sphere?

Answer (score 5):

**Using BoundaryStyle only:**

You can use `BoundaryStyle` to mark the intersections of the contour surfaces:

```
h = x^2 + y^2/9 + z^2/4 - 1;
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, z == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]], 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, _} -> Directive[Thick, Blue]}]
```

[image]

This also works with multiple contour planes:

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@Prepend[Thread[z == Range[-2, 2, .4]], h == 0],
 {x, -1,  1}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None,  ContourStyle -> None,
 BoundaryStyle -> Flatten[{Thread[Range[13] -> None], {1, _} -> Directive[Thick, Red]}]]
```

[image]

Or use

```
  ContourStyle -> Thread[Directive[Opacity[.2], RandomColor[13]]]
  (*  Hue /@ RandomReal[1, 13] instead of RandomColor[13] in version 9 *)
```

to get

[image]